# TeamCity Xcode Build Runner Configuration (Command Line)

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild, teamcity-5.0

I'm trying to setup a continuous build server with TeamCity and configure it so it can run "xcodebuild -configuration release -sdk iphoneos3.0 clean build".

i installed the plugin for teamcity-xcode integration and for the 'Build Runner' settings, i set it up as

Build Runner: Command Line

Command Executable: xcodebuild -configuration release -sdk iphoneos3.0 clean build

--The error -> [11:52:29]: RunBuildException when running build stage CallRunnerStage: Cannot run process xcodebuild -configuration "Release" : file not found
[11:52:30]: Build finished

But when i set the 'Command Executable' to just "xcodebuild", it works just fine but i need it to build the release config.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

use the field command parameters for the parameters.